How to mock EncryptedSharedPreference in android using mockito
In my class I am calling a function, in that function the first check will be to check a value is notEmpty from the sharedPreference, in this case I need to mock the shared preference. To mock it we need the context as android , but if i pass the mocked context I am facing issue as expecting Android context, My code is below, Let me know how to achieve the case like, in my main view model under a function I need to check the preference data
 **My Test class**    
                @Test
                        fun `getAndUpdateCertificateData on failure`() = runTest {
                    
                            // Call the function
                            loginViewModel.getAndUpdateCertificateData()
                    
                    
                        }
    **In View Model class**
                  fun getAndUpdateCertificateData() {
                        viewModelScope.launch {
                            if (SecuredSharedPreferenceData.certificateKeys.isEmpty()
                                && SharedContext.isSSLFeatureFlagEnabled) {

// based on the success rest of the code
                } } }
        
    **SecuredSharedPreferenceData.class**
        
        private  val securedEncryptSharedPreferences = SecureSharedPrefs.getSharedPreferences(Session.context!!, Constants.ENCRYPTED_SECURE_PREFS_FILE_NAME) // Instance of shared preference
        
        val certificateKeys: Set<String>
                get() = securedEncryptSharedPreferences.getStringSet(CERTIFICATE_KEYS, setOf()) ?: setOf()
    
    fun getSharedPreferences(context: Context, fileName:String = PREFS_FILE_NAME): SharedPreferences {
            val masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context)
                .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                .build()
            return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                context,
                fileName,
                masterKey,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
            )
        }


Please end your post with a question
